# How to save counters in perfmon tool?

Tags: windows, performance, perfmon

In `perfmon` tool `Pages/sec`, `Avg Disk Queue Length` and `% Performance Time` are default counters present in it. I want to monitor `sqlservr` counter in perfmon tool and so am adding `sqlservr`. If I close perfmon tool and reopen, am not able to see sqlservr counter which I added. How to save that so that I can monitor any time when I open? Or do I need to add `sqlservr` counter every time I open `perfmon`?

Answer (score 9):

As described in this [link](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/erin/customizing-the-default-counters-for-performance-monitor/)

*On 2008+ and Vista+*::

On your machine, select `Start | Run` and then open up Performance Monitor with the `/sys` Command-Line option: **`perfmon /sys`**

This opens Performance Monitor in a stand-alone mode (if you enter just perfmon, you get additional options such as Data Collector Sets and Reports).  Within PerfMon, add the counters you want to monitor.  Once you have added the counters, close PerfMon.

Go back to `Start | Run` and enter `perfmon /sys` again.  The counters you added should be selected.  Generally PerfMon saves a configuration file `Perfmon.PerfmonCfg` in `Users\<username>\AppData\Local`.  The location may vary.

*On 2003 and XP*::

Open up Performance Monitor `Start | Run| perfmon`. Add the counters you want to monitor.  Once you have the counters added, right-click again in the graphing area and select `Save As…` and save it as an `html file`. Then close PerfMon.

Start up PerfMon again, you should see that you only have the `% Processor Time` counter. Open the `.html file` you just saved in a text editor. Highlight everything (CTRL + A) and then copy it (CTRL + C). Switch back to PerfMon, click in the graph area and paste (CTRL + V). You can also click on the paste icon in the toolbar. The counters will immediately show up.  As with the configuration file, you can create multiple .html files to save locally or share.

Comment: Standalone mode works in Windows 10 as well. And if for some reason the counters don't load based on your config file, you can save and reload settings from the File menu. Saving the settings to a file also allows them to be used on different machines.